# PHP and Mysql, nl2br and validation error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a text area that enables users to enter text and tags  and save it to **mysql** for exmaple:

```
This is some text
<table>
<tr>
<td>
   blah
   blah
   blah
</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

When I output the text to html page if I use:

```
nl2br($text);
```

At the end of every line including tags a line break would be added:

```
This is some text<br/>
<table><br/>
<tr><br/>
<td><br/>
   blah<br/>
   blah<br/>
   blah<br/>
</td><br/>
</tr><br/>
<table><br/>
```

Obviously I get validation error because of the line break between tags for example here:

```
<tr><br/>
<td><br/>
```

If I don't use nl2br there will be no line break at all. What do I do?

Comment: If the HTML is without `br` in input, should it not be without `br` at output too then?

Comment: agree @Jite , but for the sake of the question, maybe you could try putting it in a pre tag?

Comment: pre gives validation error because table is not allowed inside pre. Unless you mean putting the text inside pre and not the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always try remove any br tag set after tag following your pass through to the nl2br.

This one liner may help.

```
<?php 

$stringToStore = str_replace('><br />', '>', nl2br($originalString));
```

Hope this helps!

---

EDIT: Untested but to better catch html tags you could use regex replacement.

```
<?php

$stringToStore = preg_replace('/(<.*>)<br\s*\\/?>/', '$1', nl2br($originalString));
```

The regex basically says:

- Caputure everything inside of `< >` followed by a `<br />`
- The brackets around the `<.*>` signify a capture group which we can access using **$1** (because its the first caputre group)
- Replace the tag followed by the `<br />`, with the caught tag.
- This will accept either `<br />`,`<br/>` or `<br>`

Like i say, this untested but should work.